# Postfix rejecting inbound mail to virtual mailboxes

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

I followed this tutorial to setup an email server that uses virtual users. https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/mailserver-with-virtual-users-and-domains-using-postfix-and-dovecot-on-a-centos-6-vps/

I am able to send emails, but when i try to send an email to one of the virtual mailboxes i get the following error in the maillog.

> Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table;

Based on the research ive done it appears that this line is the cause. Specifically "reject_unauth_destination".

```
> smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
```

I tried removing the "reject_unauth_destination" value and i then get the following error.

> fatal: in parameter smtpd_relay_restrictions or
>   smtpd_recipient_restrictions, specify at least one working instance
>   of: reject_unauth_destination, defer_unauth_destination, reject,
>   defer, defer_if_permit or check_relay_domains

Anyone know what i can do to fix this error. I can log into the account just fine and send mail. Everything seems fine except for this rejecting of emails.

Here is a full copy of my main.cf postfix file.

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_database = $alias_maps

inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost

debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
         PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
         ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5

sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES

relay_domains = *
virtual_alias_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_aliases
virtual_mailbox_domains=hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_domains
virtual_mailbox_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_mailbox

virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_minimum_uid = 2222
virtual_transport = virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:2222
virtual_gid_maps = static:2222

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated

smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
```

I have added records to the 3 vmail files to configure the account

```
 vmail_domains - mydomain.com OK
 vmail_mailbox - dan@mydomain.com mydomain.com/dan/
 vmail_aliases - dan@mydomain.com dan@mydomain.com
```

Comment: you populated virtual_mailbox_domains(using your domain) and virtual_mailbox_maps(your user mail) and after postmap and restart or reload postfix?

Comment: i have added a section that shows what i have added to vmail_comains, mailbox and aliases for the email account im currently trying to setup

Comment: the error is very clear, did you used postmap? try postmap -q dan@mydomain.com hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_mailbox

Comment: the email is already in the vmail_mailbox file and i ran postmap too. When i ran it using the command listed i got the following error. Maybe the DB isnt getting corretly updated? postmap: warning: database /etc/postfix/vmail_mailbox.db is older than source file /etc/postfix/vmail_mailbox

Looking at the timestamp i can see that vmail_mailbox.db hasnt been updated in over a month. It seems postmap isnt writing to this db anymore

Comment: use postmap /etc/postfix/vmail_mailbox and service postfix restart and try again

Answer (score 0):

the error is very clear, did you used postmap? try `postmap -q dan@mydomain.com hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_mailbox`.

for solving your problem you need to use `"postmap /etc/postfix/vmail_mailbox and service postfix"`

If you are using hash table in postfix, every time you change the text file you need to use postmap on the files to regenerate the db files.